# calculate ratio of 2 parameters group by each server IP

Tags: pandas, libreoffice-calc

I have a list of server IP addresses along ith the error code. The code starting with 2 or 3 is good and if it starts with 4 or 5 then it's bad.

```
            ip  code  value
0   10.0.1.125   200  86689
1   10.0.1.125   206     45
2   10.0.1.125   301     13
3   10.0.1.125   302    314
4   10.0.1.125   304   5115
5   10.0.1.125   400     16
6   10.0.1.125   401    212
7   10.0.1.125   403     26
8   10.0.1.125   404  12103
9   10.0.1.125   405     19
10  10.0.1.125   416      2
11  10.0.1.125   460    390
12  10.0.1.125   500   1176
13  10.0.1.125   502      1
14  10.0.1.125   503  26369
```

I need to calculate the percent of bad code count against the good.
In this case it is 0.43 (40314 / 92176)

There are several such servers in the list and for each server the ratio should be calculated.
The expected result is something like...

```
10.0.1.125 0.43
10.0.1.126 0.91
10.0.1.127 0.27
```

Comment: I added headers to your DataFrame for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### update

I realize that the "value" column should be used, so update my previous approach to first [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the code, then [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html), finally compute the ratio:

```
codes = {'2': 'good', '3': 'good', '4': 'bad', '5': 'bad'}

out = (df.assign(status=df['code'].astype(str).str[0].map(codes))
         .groupby(['ip', 'status'])['value'].sum()
         .unstack('status')
         .eval('ratio = bad/good')
       )
```

Or with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
out = (
 df.assign(status=df['code'].astype(str).str[0].map(codes))
   .pivot_table(index='ip', columns='status', values='value', aggfunc='sum')
   .eval('ratio = bad/good')
   .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
           ip    bad   good     ratio
0  10.0.1.125  40314  92176  0.437359
```

##### previous answer (not the wanted logic)

You can use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) after a `map` to convert the codes to good/bad:

```
# set up mapper for codes
codes = {'2': 'good', '3': 'good', '4': 'bad', '5': 'bad'}

# count the good/bad codes per ip
tmp = pd.crosstab(df['ip'], df['code'].astype(str).str[0].map(codes))

# compute the ratio
tmp['bad']/tmp['good']
```

*NB. if the codes are integers and always 3 digits, you can also map with `df['code'].floordiv(100).map(codes)`, just change the keys of `d` to be integers.*

Output:

```
ip
10.0.1.125    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Alternatively, with a [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
(df.assign(good=df['code'].astype(str).str.match('[23]'),
           bad=df['code'].astype(str).str.match('[45]'),
          )
   .groupby('ip', as_index=False)[['good', 'bad']].sum()
   .eval('ratio = bad/good')
)
```

Output:

```
           ip  good  bad  ratio
0  10.0.1.125     5   10    2.0
```